# TableView commitEditingStyle property conditionally in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

In my project, there are two different view controllers but both of them use the same **nib** file. In that nib file, there is a tableview. My problem is that **commitEditingStyle .Delete** property should be included for the first view controller, but not for the second view controller. How can I ensure this condition. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Thank you for your answers,

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would help:

```
-[UITableViewDataSource tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:]
```

Comment: Perhaps a little more explanation would help :)